# Remove this [usage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

[usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usage) (400+ Questions) is too ambiguous to be kept around. Some Questions add the tag just because there is a concept if *using* something in the body. Some have tags like [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory)[usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usage), and should either be made [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage) or just re-tagged to [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage).

Comment: Went through 30 or so replacing usage with the usage-kind(s) they actually meant, and downvoting crap (Some were actually only grossly mis-tagged). Still, there's plenty left, for anyone who wants his own piece.

Comment: What, nobody's an expert on usage?

Comment: @Neolisk Sure, I'm an expert on usage. I use utensils, I use a gym, and every once in a while, I even use my brain. Now where's my gold tag badge?!

Comment: +1: I like the (probably updated) description of [usage]: "DO NOT USE"

Comment: Why does the tag even exist?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - perhaps the users using the tag were using something

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Done!

Ironic comment found while burninating: "I feel used"

Most needed to be retagged memory-management or cpu-usage, or just deleted entirely (they were about using some function or language feature).